# Ошибка при запуске Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

Установил недавно локальный сервер на комп но заметил что PHPMyAdmin не запускается, выдавая ошибку
 **#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. `<br />`Сервер не отвечает (либо локальный сокет сервера MySQL неверно настроен).**
Полез в mysql.log там выдает такие строчки:
*InnoDB: The Auto-extending innodb_system data file '.\ibdata1' is of a different size 4864 pages (rounded down to MB) than specified in the .cnf file: initial 6400 pages, max 0 (relevant if non-zero) pages!

InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error

Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

Failed to initialize plugins.

Aborting*
 ПОМОГИТЕ ИСПРАВИТЬ!

Comment: Повреждено табличное пространство InnoDB, ничего с ним не делали вручную? Поломке предшествовали какие-то операции с MySQL, может быть восстанавливали базы данных?

Comment: InnoDB я не трогал, только установил сервер на комп

Comment: Ну так попробуйте снести и поставить заново, раз у вас там ещё ничего нет